How to switch to a parent tab on sub-tab swipe in Flutter?
I'm building a Flutter app with nested TabBarView widgets. The parent tab has two main tabs ("Tab 1" and "Tab 2"). Inside "Tab 2", there are sub-tabs ("Sub Tab 1", "Sub Tab 2", etc.) implemented using a second TabBarView.
I want to go to Main Tab 1 when user swipe left from Sub Tab 1.
Specially how can I detect if someone swipe left from Sub Tab 1? So i can easily animate to Main Tab 1.
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2, // Parent tabs
      child: Builder( // Use Builder to get a proper context for the parent DefaultTabController
        builder: (BuildContext parentContext) {

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Tabs Example'),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                // Main TabBar
                const TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      // First Tab Content
                      const Center(child: Text('This is Tab 1')),

                      // Second Tab with Sub-tabs
                      DefaultTabController(
                        length: 4,
                        child: Scaffold(
                          appBar: AppBar(
                            bottom: const TabBar(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                              tabs: [
                                Tab(text: 'Sub Tab 1'),
                                Tab(text: 'Sub Tab 2'),
                                Tab(text: 'Sub Tab 3'),
                                Tab(text: 'Sub Tab 4'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          body: const TabBarView(
                            children: [
                              Center(child: Text('Content for Sub Tab 1')),
                              Center(child: Text('Content for Sub Tab 2')),
                              Center(child: Text('Content for Sub Tab 3')),
                              Center(child: Text('Content for Sub Tab 4')),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


You can achieve this by using tabbarcontroller. But you need some more custom functionality. I think you can try gesture detector widget.
 final PageController _parentPageController = PageController();
  int _currentParentTabIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2, 
      child: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext parentContext) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Tabs Example'),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                // Main TabBar
                const TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: PageView(
                    controller: _parentPageController,
                    onPageChanged: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentParentTabIndex = index;
                      });
                    },
                    children: [
                      // First Tab Content
                      const Center(child: Text('This is Tab 1')),

                      // Second Tab with Sub-tabs
                      DefaultTabController(
                        length: 4,
                        child: Scaffold(
                          appBar: AppBar(
                            bottom: const TabBar(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                              tabs: [
                                Tab(text: 'Sub Tab 1'),
                                Tab(text: 'Sub Tab 2'),
                                Tab(text: 'Sub Tab 3'),
                                Tab(text: 'Sub Tab 4'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          body: GestureDetector(
                            onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                              // Check if the swipe was to the left
                              if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 0) {
                                // If currently on Sub Tab 1, navigate to Main Tab 1
                                if (TabController.of(parentContext)!.index == 1) {
                                  if (TabController.of(context)!.index == 0) {
                                    _parentPageController.jumpToPage(0);
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            child: const TabBarView(
                              children: [
                                Center(child: Text('Content for Sub Tab 1')),
                                Center(child: Text('Content for Sub Tab 2')),
                                Center(child: Text('Content for Sub Tab 3')),
                                Center(child: Text('Content for Sub Tab 4')),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
}

